# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect - Mapping Shared Network Drive (ASP.NET MVC3 C#)

Tags: c#, iis

Hello I am attempting to copy a file over to a shared network but I continue getting the error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`. Could someone please catch what I am doing incorrectly. Also my Application is running using ASP.NET MVC3, Thanks!


**copy code**

```
File.Copy(@path, @Properties.Settings.Default.SharedMappedOutput);
```

---

*The path is a parameter:* `C:\log\12345.pdf` 
*Properties.Settings.Default.SharedMappedOutput Path:* `\\vfler_xx\evl_xx\VT\` .

What I want to accomplish: I want to copy the file from `Path` (filename) to `SharedMappedOutput` (directory)

---

Extra information

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- ASP.NET MVC3 C#

---

**EDIT**

I have changed my code with the help of @Steve, but now it is saying I do not have access to a path that I did not specify.

```
String dest_path = Properties.Settings.Default.SharedMappedOutput;
File.Copy(@path, Path.Combine(dest_path, Path.GetFileName(path)));
```

**ERROR** 
`Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\insetsrv\12345.pdf' is denied`
I did not specify this path, I am not sure why it is trying to access this path. 
Link to the new problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179585/iis-acccess-to-the-path-c-windows-system32-inetsrv-12345-pdf-is-denied

---

Thank you. Please let me know if there is any questions or misunderstanding in the question. Thanks in advance again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File.Copy doesn't copy a directory to another directory, but just a filename.

Your `c:\log` seems to be just the name of a directory and as stated by the [documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) this doesn't work

To copy all the file in the source path you could write this

```
string destPath = Properties.Settings.Default.SharedMappedOutput;
foreach (string aFile in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*"))
     File.Copy(aFile, Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(aFile)));
```

**EDIT**
Seeing the comment about the real source name then the answer is still partially valid because also the destination should be a filename and not a directory. So the answer becomes

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\log\12345.pdf";
string destPath = Properties.Settings.Default.SharedMappedOutput;
File.Copy(sourceFile, Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile)));
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part, the first parameter is a filename. Thank you for the reply

Comment: Well, however also the destination should be a file and not a path. Look at my answer how the destination file name is built

Comment: Okay so when I am handling one file rather then a directory it would be  `File.Copy(path, Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(path)));` Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you, and this copies sourceFile over to destPath?

Comment: Yes, just check the docs: `Overwriting a file of the same name is not allowed.`

Comment: I have made the changes, but it seems like I am getting a new error. Please reload the page I have made an edit. Thanks again for the assitance.

Comment: You are running from IIS and, under the default configuration, you can't access files outside the site home directory. I will try to use the [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method with various version of the path parameter, but I am not sure that this could resolve your current problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help Steve. I made a new post for my new problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with using a UNC path if I remember correctly. Map the share as a mapped drive and it will work like a charm.

here is an example on mapping the unc path to a mapped drive.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6847/Map-Network-Drive-API

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for the reply! How exactly do I `Map the share as a mapped drive`?